# How to retrieve data using Entity Framework LINQ to Entities with self referencing table using includes and joins?

Tags: entity-framework, linq, join, code-first, self-reference

Database table called `Events` that contains event templates from which any number of single events can be generated that have a foreign key relationship referencing the same Event table with the template event ID as the primary key, so a self referencing table. There is another table called `EventRestriction` which has a foreign key to both the Event table and a `Customer` table. The foreign key value to the Event table is the event ID of the event template record. What I am struggling to do is the following:

From the Event table get ALL events whose event template ID matches the event ID in the `EventRestriction` table and where the customer ID in the `EventRestriction` table equals a specific customer.

This is using EF 6 code first approach against SQL Server 2012.

This is the existing query that I am trying to build on;

```
var query = Events
                .Include(x => x.Location)
                .Include(x => x.Facility)
                .Include(x => x.EventType)
                .Include("Tickets.WebSaleItem.Product")
                .Include("Tickets.SeatingTemplateCategory")
                .Include("Tickets.SeatReservations")
                .Include(x => x.SeatingTemplate.SeatingUser)
                .Include(x => x.SeatingTemplate.SeatingTemplateCategories)
                .Include("Facilities.Facility")
                .Include("EventCapacityDistributions.CapacityDistributionSource")
                .Include("EventCapacityDistributions.EventCapacityUsages.WebSaleItem.Product")
                .Include("EventCapacityUsages.Bookings.EventBookingFacilities.Facility")
                .Include("EventCapacityUsages.EventBookingReservation.EventBookingFacilities.Facility")
                .AsQueryable();
```

I have to use this is a base query as all of the includes are required for further processing against the initial result set.

I have tried the following so far.

I have declared the routing relationship between `Event`, `EventRestriction` and `Customer` so there are many-to-many relationships and hashsets defined with the appropriate (I think) navigation properties.

I added this to the above query

```
query = query.Where (x => x.EventRestriction.Any (tte => tte.CustomerID == customerID));
```

This returns the single template event based upon event ID and customer ID.

I then tried this:

```
query = query.Where(x => x.EventRestriction.Any (tte => (tte.CustomerID == customerID && tte.EventID == x.EventID) || (tte.EventID == x.EventTemplate.EventID && tte.CustomerID == customerID)));
```

My thinking was that doing the OR would do it but no joy and I get the same result as previous with just the single event.

I am thinking that I am going in the right direction but missing a vital element.

One thing that did work for me though was doing this before building query:

```
List<Guid> ttEventIDs = new List<Guid>();

ttEventIDs = EventRestriction.Select(tte => tte.EventID).ToList();
```

I then used the resulting list like this;

```
query = query.Where(x => ttEventIDs.Contains(x.EventTemplate.EventID));
```

Now this did give me the results I was expecting BUT using a contains is not really going to work as the number of ID's could be huge!!!

I am thinking a table join would work better?

So basically what I expect is that if `Event` table contains a template event from which 100 individual events have been generated with an `EventTemplateID` foreign keyed to the original template event ID AND `EventRestriction` table contains one single record that comprising of the 'CustomerID' and the `EventID` of the original template my query needs to return NOT the single event record BUT the 100 events whose `EventTemplateID` matches the `EventRestriction` event ID.

I hope this makes sense? Any guidance will be greatly appreciated.

Comment: Side note, `.Include(x => xTickets.Select(y => y.WebSaleItem.Product))` works as well, if you feel more comfortable with the Expression route rather than switching back to the `Include(string)` version.

Comment: So, `EventRestrictions` is the `join-table` between `Events` and `Customers` tables? which has `EventTemplateID` as a foreign key to `Events` and `CustomerID` as a foreign to `Customers` table? It's not obvious to me why you're using `Any` on `EventRestriction` while it's not a collection, it has to be an object, one object

Comment: I cant believe I left out a key fact that the PRIMARY KEY for the EventRestriction table is a composite of EventID & CustomerID to ensure unique combinations, apologies! The situation is that the EventRestriction table can contain many EventIDs and the Event table can contain many events whose EventTemplateID is FK'd back to the Event table. What I need to retrieve is ALL of the Events whose EventTemplateID matches the EventRestriction EventID, NOT the Event table EventID, this is where I am stuck. Is this any clearer or have I made it worse?